# What is with this error? ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: executenonquery

Please help guys. It works perfectly when updating without the current password and the new password BUT if i will include to update the password, it throws an error. Here's my code:

```
    protected void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        int queryStrId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("Id"));
        string query = "";

// Works fine here..
        if (CurrPass.Text == "" && NewPass.Text == "")
        {
            query = "UPDATE RegDetails SET Firstname = '" + FirstName.Text + "', Lastname = '" + LastName.Text + "', Gender = " + gender + ", AddressLocation = '" + Address.Text + "', Position = '" + Position.Text + "', CurrentStatus = " + status + ", Username = '" + Username.Text + "' WHERE Id = " + queryStrId;
        }
// Does not work. Display error "ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized". What's wrong with this?
        else
        {
            if (CurrPass.Text != "" && NewPass.Text != "" && CurrPass.Text == currentPassword)
            {
                query = "UPDATE RegDetails SET Firstname = '" + FirstName.Text + "', Lastname = '" + LastName.Text + "', Gender = " + gender + ", AddressLocation = '" + Address.Text + "', Position = '" + Position.Text + "', CurrentStatus = " + status + ", Username = '" + Username.Text + "', Password = '" + NewPass.Text + "' WHERE Id = " + queryStrId;
            }
        }

        SqlCommand commandUpdate = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        commandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This must be evaluating to false:

`if (CurrPass.Text != "" && NewPass.Text != "" && CurrPass.Text == currentPassword)`

Also, use parameterized SQL for pete's sake.